# Kinematic Problem, two balls thrown down from building at different times, when will they meet and what distance will they hit at?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

You drop a ball from a building on the road $40\, \mathrm{m}$ below. Your friend beside you throws a second ball 1 second later at $25\,\mathrm{m/s}$, trying to hit your ball in mid-air. Assuming the aim is good, how high does it hit.

So I started by stating my variables

- initial distance of ball one and two: $40\, \mathrm{m}$
- final distance of ball one and two: $0$
- Initial velocity of one: $0\,\mathrm{ m/s}$
- Initial velocity of two: $25\,\mathrm{m/s}$
- Final velocity of one: ?            Final velocity of two: ?
- acceleration of one and two: $9.81\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$

This is all I know. I started by using a kinematic equation on ball one: 
$$2ad=v_f^2-v_i^2$$

subbing what I know gives me $2(9.81)(40)=v_f^2 - 0^2\to v_f=28.01\,\mathrm{m/s}$

I used this value along with other knowns in the another equation to find time: 
$v_f=v_i+a t\to 28.01=0+9.81 \,t \to t= 2.855\,\mathrm{s}$

Ok, now I have the time the first ball took to fall, now I will use the exact same process for the second ball:

$$2ad=v_f^2-v_i^2 \to 2(9.81)(40)=v_f^2-25^2 \to v_f=37.54 \mathrm{m/s}$$

Now I'll plug that number into the other kinematic equation

$$v_f=v_i+a t \to 37.54=25+9.81\,t \to t=1.275\,\mathrm{ s}$$

Since this ball was thrown a second after the first, I'll add one second to the time above: $1.275+1= 2.275$.

Since this time is faster than the time for the first ball, that means they do meet. But now how do I find that out? I tried to make kinematics equations equal each other but I get nowhere since all the distances cancel out. Please help.

Comment: Hi Nabil.Please read the guidelines regarding homework problems by following this link;meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/…

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Who does upvote such type of homework-questions? Really horrendous:(

Comment: Initial distance of ball 1 and 2 is NOT 40 m. 1 second after being dropped ball 1 is just 5 m ($\frac12 gt^2$) away. That should help.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site I didn;t know.. And Floris, could you please explain why the initial distance is not 40 for ball one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both must travel the same displacement in order to collide with each other. Try using the kinematic equation $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. Remember that as Socre said, one will have travelled the displacement in $x$ seconds, while other in $(x-1)$ seconds as it was thrown 1 second after and that the displacement of the ball 1 = the displacement of the ball 2 as they collide.

Comment: So, would I just turn the equation above into **_ut+1/2at^2=ut+1/2at^2_**?

Answer (score 2):

For the second ball to reach the first ball, they must reach the same height at the same time,
We should have an equation which ties this  together; when the balls hit each other, an observer would have found a time $t$ on his stop watch  in which$t=t_{1}$, ball two must reach that height in that time but there is a one second gap, so we have, 
$$t_{2}=t_{1}-1$$

Comment: Please don't post complete or near-complete answers to homework-like questions. It is against the policy of this site to completely provide answer to a homework-question which doesn't ask for a specific physics concept. This is not a homework-solving site. We discourage such answers which act as complete solution to such questions. Check our [homework-policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for more clarification.

Comment: @user36790 noted